# "times out while waiting for program to exit" Find in Cs50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm still new to coding so please bear with me. I've been trying to figure out what's been wrong with my code. Whenever I use check50 -l minprog/cs50x/2020/find; i have multiple down faces and says that it timed out whilst waiting for program to exit. Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?
Some smiles are up, most of them are down. Am I stuck in a loop somewhere?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "helpers.h"


bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // return false if n is a non-integer
    if (n < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // initialize the middle index of the array
    // and set the min and max of array
       int minimum = 0, maximum = n - 1;
       int middle = (maximum - minimum) / 2 + minimum;

    // while n is a positive integer, check if the middle equals the value
    while (n > 0)
    {
        // check if the value is the same as the middle of the array
       if (value == values[middle])
       {
           return true;
       }

       // make the middle + 1 more index as the min
       // if the value is more than the middle
       else if (value > values[middle])
       {
           minimum = middle + 1;

        // make the middle - 1 less index as the max if the value is
        // less than the middle
       }
       else if (value < values[middle])
       {
           maximum = middle - 1;
       }

       // declare the new amount of numbers from the array after 'cutting'
       n = maximum - minimum + 1;
    }

    // return false if value can't be found
    return false;
}

void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // loop over the array until i is smaller than the last index
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        // initialize the minimum, i starts at the beginning so it is also minimum
        int minimum = i;


        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            // check if the minimum value is bigger than the jth value
            // if yes, set the jth int as the minimum
            if (values[minimum] > values[j])
            {
                minimum = j;
            }
        }

        // check to see if the minimum is not the same as i
        if (minimum != i)
        {
            // switch i with the lowest int
            int temporary_int = values[minimum];
            values[minimum] = values[i];
            values[i] = temporary_int;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I suggest improving your question explaining at least what your program is supposed to do. The checker obviously complains your program takes too long to execute. But... takes too long to do what??? As it is, your question is too broad.

Comment: Does the program *ever* end? Run it in your own environment to find out. The `search()` function looks like an attempt at a binary sreach of a sorted array, but it isn't.

Comment: What is the purpose of `middle` in `search` function? Does it fullfil that purpose?

Comment: in `search` the variable `middle` is never modified even though `n` is.